# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/etc/reaver’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, mkdir, permission-denied

I am trying to install `reaver` and I am stuck at a point were it says to `install make`.

When I enter command `make install` the following message appears:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/reaver /usr/local/bin/wash /usr/local/bin/walsh
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc/reaver ]; 
then 
      mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/reaver;
fi
```

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/etc/reaver’: Permission denied
>   Makefile:88: recipe for target 'install' failed
>   make: *** [install] Error 1

How can i solve this?

Comment: Do you have permission to change `/usr/` or its contents? An ordinary user on Linux usually does not have those permissions.

Comment: `make install` usually need some high previlidges, if you are very *sure what are you doing*, you can use `sudo make install`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether your user has permission on that path. OR try with root user(not recommended) OR try with `sudo make install`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to allow permission to execute that file. `chmod +x filename.run`
and try to run using the root user.
[image]